# Can external interrupts be OR'd together on the '328 (Uno)?

Tags: arduino-uno, interrupt

I'm thinking about how to handle a rotary encoder. I'm planning on using interrupts and would like to use both the 'A' and 'B' phase transitions to generate interrupts. I'm wondering if there is any reason why the signals couldn't be OR'd together to generate the interrupt so that I wouldn't need to consume both external interrupts for the encoder.

Comment: You still need to read both signals regardless, so you only end up using an extra pin.

Comment: I know I'd still need to use two pins to read the state of the encoder, but I was hoping to use one interrupt pin and one non-interrupt pin and still be able to get full resolution from the encoder.

Comment: All ATmega328P pins support pin change interrupts.

Comment: Yes, but my understanding is that the "internal" interrupt latency and/or software overhead is much higher than it is for the "external" interrupts – so I was hoping to find a way to use a single external interrupt. I have't actually measure the difference yet, so I don't know how big a hit it would be to use the internal interrupts for this application. But the question is also generally interesting if the technique could be used in other situations as well.

Answer (score 3):

Regarding the notion that “"internal" interrupt latency and/or software overhead is much higher than it is for the "external" interrupts”, it certainly is true that PCI (pin-change interrupts) libraries [`PinChangeInt.h` (deprecated)](https://github.com/GreyGnome/PinChangeInt/commit/ec745f854b2b807640341cf479f540bb8bb3fc2f) and [`EnableInterrupt.h`](https://github.com/GreyGnome/EnableInterrupt) have high software overhead.  By keeping track of former values, for each pin those libraries support separate callback routines for Rising, Falling, Change, High, and Low.  PCIs are grouped in sets of eight pins per interrupt vector, leading to 40 different cases of callback routines when a PCI fires.  That is, when a PCI occurs, the libraries quickly find out which set of pins changed – because that's what the hardware supports – but then they go through all eight pins on the vector one by one checking if it changed, and how it changed, then calling the callback associated with the particular pin and its particular state.

For reading pins of a rotary encoder, say a [KY-040](https://www.google.com/search?q=ky-040+rotary+encoder&biw=1095&bih=625&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiN8-KEv4XKAhVU2mMKHVxYBPIQsAQIGw), the overhead described above can cause loss of 10%–20% of rotary counts.  If you are concerned about not losing counts, write your own `ISR()`-level interrupt service routine.  The example below illustrates a routine using `ISR()`; this example is from my [answer to previous question #18221](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/a/18221/3917), with some comments added here and there.  See that answer for discussion of the timing data that is this program's output.  (For rotary encoder quadrature-counting, see discussion below).

```c
/*  rcTiming.ino -- JW, 30 November 2015 -- 
 * Uses pin-change interrupts on A0-A4 to time RC pulses
 *
 * Ref: https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/18183/read-rc-receiver-channels-using-interrupt-instead-of-pulsein
 *
 */
#include <Streaming.h>
static   byte rcOld;        // Prev. states of inputs
volatile unsigned long rcRises[4]; // times of prev. rising edges
volatile unsigned long rcTimes[4]; // recent pulse lengths
volatile unsigned int  rcChange=0; // Change-counter

// Be sure to call setup_rcTiming() from setup()
void setup_rcTiming() {
  rcOld = 0;
  // Note, if using an encoder without pullups on it,
  // change INPUT in next 2 lines to INPUT_PULLUP
  pinMode(A0, INPUT);  // pin 14, A0, PC0, for pin-change interrupt
  pinMode(A1, INPUT);  // pin 15, A1, PC1, for pin-change interrupt
  pinMode(A2, INPUT);
  pinMode(A3, INPUT);
  PCMSK1 |= 0x0F;       // Four-bit mask for four channels
  PCIFR  |= 0x02;       // clear pin-change interrupts if any
  PCICR  |= 0x02;       // enable pin-change interrupts
}
// Define the service routine for PCI vector 1
ISR(PCINT1_vect) {
  byte rcNew = PINC & 15;   // Get low 4 bits, A0-A3
  byte changes = rcNew^rcOld;   // Notice changed bits
  byte channel = 0;
  unsigned long now = micros(); // micros() is ok in int routine
  while (changes) {
    if ((changes & 1)) {  // Did current channel change?
      if ((rcNew & (1<<channel))) { // Check rising edge
        rcRises[channel] = now;     // Is rising edge
      } else {              // Is falling edge
        rcTimes[channel] = now-rcRises[channel];
      }
    }
    changes >>= 1;      // shift out the done bit
    ++channel;
    ++rcChange;
  }
  rcOld = rcNew;        // Save new state
}

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  Serial.println("Starting RC Timing Test");
  setup_rcTiming();
}

void loop() {
  unsigned long rcT[4]; // copy of recent pulse lengths
  unsigned int rcN;
  if (rcChange) {

    // Data is subject to races if interrupted, so off interrupts
    cli();          // Disable interrupts
    rcN = rcChange;
    rcChange = 0;       // Zero the change counter
    rcT[0] = rcTimes[0];
    rcT[1] = rcTimes[1];
    rcT[2] = rcTimes[2];
    rcT[3] = rcTimes[3];
    sei();          // reenable interrupts

    Serial << "t=" << millis() << " " << rcT[0] << " " << rcT[1]
       << " " << rcT[2] << " " << rcT[3] << " " << rcN << endl;
  }
  sei();            // reenable interrupts
}
```

Note, for the above you may need to download and install `Streaming.h` via [`Streaming5.zip`](http://arduiniana.org/Streaming/Streaming5.zip) from [arduiniana.org](http://arduiniana.org/libraries/streaming/).

**Rotary encoder quadrature-counting**

The program above tracks and reports pulse-length times, instead of decoding the quadrature signals the rotary encoder provides.  The program below reports rotary encoder counts, but does so using INT0 and INT1 instead of PCIs.  You will want to combine relevant portions of the two routines together – ie, use the interrupt setup and handling framework from above, with the body of the service routine from below.  [Note, this program is from my [answer to previous question #16420](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/a/16420/3917).  The encoder decoding code within it is faster and shorter than other decoding code I've looked at, and is fast enough to support two encoders rotating simultaneously while losing few counts.]

```c
/*  roto_jw4.ino -- JW, 29 September 2015 -- 
 *  A 4-state state-machine implementation of rotary
 *  encoding for KY-040 rotary knobs.  The state-machine picture at
 *  https://e2e.ti.com/support/microcontrollers/hercules/f/312/t/318762
 *  in a Feb 4, 2014 7:40 PM post by Anthony Seely shows counts
 *  increasing on transitions 10 -> 11 -> 01 -> 00 -> 10 and
 *  decreasing on transitions the other way.  Transitions between 00
 *  and 11 or 10 and 01 are invalid.  This code detects valid
 *  transitions by (abOld xor abNew) equaling 1 or 2.  It detects
 *  up-count events by the tri-bit value ABA' (where A' is the new
 *  reading on pin A) being equal to 1, 2, 5, or 6 (a bit mask of
 *  0x66), and down-count events by ABA' being equal to 0, 3, 4, or 7
 *  (a bit mask of 0x99).
 *
 *  On a KY-040 unit I tested, there are 30 detent positions per turn.
 *  With this unit the code generates 60 counts per turn, which can be
 *  seen individually as one turns the rotor slowly.  Odd counts
 *  appear between detents, even counts at detents.
 *
 *  Set quadrature-signal pin numbers, via PinA and PinB constants.
 *  Set IPINMODE to INPUT_PULLUP if there are no external pull-ups
 *  on encoder AB pins, else set IPINMODE to INPUT
 */
enum { PinA=2, PinB=3, IPINMODE=INPUT };

static  byte abOld;     // Initialize state
volatile int count;     // current rotary count
         int old_count;     // old rotary count

void setup() {
  pinMode(PinA, IPINMODE);
  pinMode(PinB, IPINMODE);
  attachInterrupt(0, pinChangeISR, CHANGE); // Set up pin-change interrupts
  attachInterrupt(1, pinChangeISR, CHANGE);
  abOld = count = old_count = 0;
  Serial.begin(115200);
  Serial.println("Starting Rotary Encoder Test");
}

// On interrupt, read input pins, compute new state, and adjust count
void pinChangeISR() {
  enum { upMask = 0x66, downMask = 0x99 };
  byte abNew = (digitalRead(PinA) << 1) | digitalRead(PinB);
  byte criterion = abNew^abOld;
  if (criterion==1 || criterion==2) {
    if (upMask & (1 << (2*abOld + abNew/2)))
      count++;
    else count--;       // upMask = ~downMask
  }
  abOld = abNew;        // Save new state
}

void loop() {
  if (old_count != count) {
    Serial.print(millis());
    Serial.print("  ");
    Serial.println(count);
    old_count = count;
  }
}
```

**Using other pins for PCIs**

If you wish to monitor two rotary encoder lines using pin change interrupts on pins other than A0 and A1, you *may* need to replace vector `PCINT1_vect` with some other vector, and *will* need to replace the pins mask with a different one.  The following program can be used to display a table of PCI vectors, masks, etc.  (As noted in my question [Why PJ0 and PJ1 are not reporting as PCINT pins](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/q/16551), pins PJ0 and PJ1 on an ATmega-2560 board will not report correctly.)

```c
/*  pinsList -- JW, 4 October 2015 --
 *
 *  Displays a list of Arduino pin numbers for current kind of Arduino
 *  board, along with port codes, pin-change-interrupt numbers, and
 *  pin-change-interrupt vector numbers.
 *
 *  Here are two examples of output lines for pin 11, the first for an
 *  Uno, the second for a Mega:
 *
 *        11   PB3   0x04   PWM   PCINT3  PCINT0_vect
 *        11   PB5   0x20   PWM   PCINT5  PCINT0_vect
 */
//-----------------------------------------------------------
// Given a value with 1 bit set, return bit #.  Else return 9.
byte getBitfromBV (byte m) {
  byte b=0, v=1;
  while (v) {
    if (m==v)
      return b;
    ++b; v <<= 1;
  }
  return 9;
}
//-----------------------------------------------------------
void processPinNumber(byte pin) {
  char buffi[128];      // We create text-to-write in buffi
  byte nbuff=0;         // #chars used in buffi
  byte nPCICR;          // 0, 1, or 2 for mask-register #
  byte bitInByte;       // 0 to 7 for bit in I/O mask
  byte pinPort;         // pin's port #, in range 1 to 12
  byte PCInum;          // PCINT# if pin is a PCI pin
  char *portLet = "?ABCDEFGHIJKL";

  if (pin >= NUM_DIGITAL_PINS) return;

  pinPort = digitalPinToPort(pin); // Get port #, in range 1 to 12
  bitInByte = getBitfromBV(digitalPinToBitMask(pin));

  nbuff = snprintf(buffi, sizeof(buffi), "  %2d   P%c%d  0x%02x", 
           pin, portLet[pinPort], bitInByte, 1<<bitInByte);

  // Indicate if it's a PWM pin
  if (digitalPinHasPWM(pin)) {
    nbuff += snprintf(buffi+nbuff, sizeof(buffi)-nbuff, "  PWM");
  } else {
    nbuff += snprintf(buffi+nbuff, sizeof(buffi)-nbuff, "     ");
  }

  // If it's a PCINT pin, show its PCINT number and 0, 1, 2 for its vector #
  if (digitalPinToPCICR(pin)) {      // Is it a PCint pin?
    nPCICR = digitalPinToPCICRbit(pin); // 0, 1, 2 for pin's PCICR bit#
    PCInum = nPCICR*8 + bitInByte;
    nbuff += snprintf(buffi+nbuff, sizeof(buffi)-nbuff,
             "  PCINT%d  PCINT%d_vect",  PCInum,  nPCICR);
  }
  Serial.println(buffi);
}
void setup() {
  delay(50);
  Serial.begin(115200);
  delay(50);
  while (!Serial) ;             // wait for serial stream to connect
  Serial.println("\nPin#  Port  Mask  PWM   PCINT");
  for (byte p=0; p<NUM_DIGITAL_PINS; ++p)
    processPinNumber(p);
  Serial.end();
}

void loop() {
}
```

**ISR-framework-generating Sketch**

The program below generates frameworks for specified PCI pins and prints them to `Serial`.  See usage comments within the program.  This provides an easy way to create the basic outline of an ISR to handle PCIs.

```c
/*  pinFunctions -- JW, 1 October 2015 --
 *
 *  Displays direct pin-access and pin-change-interrupt setup code,
 *  for inclusion in a sketch, for specified pin numbers.  The
 *  displayed code can be pasted into a sketch where execution speed
 *  matters.
 *
 *  When called with a call like `genCode ("affix", "9,11");`, genCode
 *  will produce a set of procedures: ISR routines for pins that
 *  support pin-change interrupts; get and put routines to read from
 *  or store to registers; and a setup routine.  The generated get,
 *  put, and setup routines will have names formed by suffixing the
 *  affix to get, put, and setup, respectively.  For example, if the
 *  affix is ML47 the names of generated routines will include
 *  getML47, putML47, and setupML47.
 *
 *  Generated get() and put() code is of the following forms (in which
 *  u, v are port-letters; values mu, mv, ni are numerical constants;
 *  and w is a parameter value) if all the pins, n1, ... nk in the
 *  pins-list are in port u, under mask mu:
 *
 *             return PINu & 0xmu; // Get pins n1, ... nk 
 *             PORTu = PINu & ~mu | w & mu;
 *
 * For example, with Uno pins 3, 4, 6, get() and put() bodies are:
 *
 *             return PIND & 0x58;
 *             PORTD = PIND & 0xa7 | w & 0x58;
 *
 *  The following forms arise if the pins are in ports u and v; and so
 *  forth if more than two ports are involved.
 *
 *             return PINu & masku | PINv & mv; // Get pins n1, ... nk
 *             PORTu = w & 0xmu;   // Put pins <u pins>
 *             PORTv = w & 0xmv;   // Put pins <v pins>
 *
 *  genCode() does not require that all pins belong to the same port.
 *  It will produce usually-desired results if bit positions don't
 *  interfere, otherwise may not.  For example: An Arduino Uno
 *  pins-list "2,10" corresponds to port pins PD2 and PB2.  Both are
 *  in bit position 2, so get's result will be the OR of the PB2 and
 *  PD2 values, while put will store the same bit value to both pins.
 *
 *  To use the pasted code: A statement like `w = getAFFIX();` will
 *  read a set of pins and store the value in w.  A statement like
 *  `putAFFIX(w);` will write w to a set of pins.  Also, add a line
 *  like the following in setup():
 *
 *       setupAFFIX(ioMode, enablePCI);
 *
 *  In the `setupAFFIX(ioMode, enablePCI);` call, substitute an
 *  appropriate affix in place of AFFIX; substitute one of INPUT,
 *  OUTPUT, or INPUT_PULLUP in place of ioMode; and substitute 1 or 0
 *  for enablePCI, to enable or not enable pin-change-interrupt setup.
 *
 *  If you want to save room and don't plan to use pin-change
 *  interrupts, instead of merely not enabling PCI setup, you can
 *  remove the ISR routines and the `if (enablePCI) {...}` section
 *  from the pasted code.
 *
 *  Each generated ISR routines contains one line, of form
 *
 *        byte datum = PINu & mu; // Read pins <list>
 *
 *  The idea is that you will paste the generated ISR into your
 *  sketch, then populate it with appropriate interrupt processing
 *  code.  Note 1: datum contains data from one port, a port which
 *  belongs to the interrupt vector.  If you need data from other
 *  ports as well, then paste appropriate lines from the get() routine
 *  into the ISR.  Note 2: This version of pinFunctions does not
 *  announce pins that don't belong to PCI vectors, if any.
 *  (Processor pins with functions like PCINT0 ... PCINT23 belong to
 *  PCI vectors.)  You can compare the masks used in get() to those
 *  used in the ISR's to detect this.  If the masks differ, some pins
 *  aren't PCI pins.  Note 3: If multiple ports' pins belong to one
 *  vector (eg Ard#0 or PE0 for PCINT8 and Ard#15 or PJ0 for PCINT9,
 *  both on vector PCINT1_vect), a code-generation error of form "Pin
 *  x's port #y isn't #z" will appear and you will need to paste in
 *  appropriate lines from get() or otherwise manually prepare correct
 *  code.
 */

char buffi[128];        // We create text-to-write in buffi
char buffn[32];         // also in buffn
byte nbuff=0;           // #chars used in buffn
char *c;            // c points into pinsList
byte pin;           // pin number
byte nPCICR;            // 0, 1, or 2 for mask-register #
byte vecmask;           // OR of 1<<nPCICR values
byte intmask[3];        // OR of int. enable masks
byte maskBitPC;         // 0 to 7 for bit in PCI mask
byte maskBitIO;         // 0 to 7 for bit in I/O mask
byte pinPort;           // pin's port #, in range 1 to 12
byte PCInum;            // PCINT# if pin is a PCI pin

// Given a value with 1 bit set, return bit #.  Else return 9.
byte getBitfromBV (byte m) {
  byte b=0, v=1;
  while (v) {
    if (m==v)
      return b;
    ++b; v <<= 1;
  }
  return 9;
}

// Get next pin number from pinsList, and its associated reg numbers
byte getPinNumber() {
  byte cc=*c;
  if (!cc)
    return 0;
  pin=0;
  for (; '0' <= cc && '9' >= cc; cc=*++c) {
    pin = 10*pin + cc - '0';
  }
  pinPort = maskBitIO = PCInum = nPCICR = maskBitPC = 0;
  if (pin < NUM_DIGITAL_PINS) {
    pinPort = digitalPinToPort(pin); // Get port #, in range 1 to 12
    maskBitIO = digitalPinToBitMask(pin);
    if (digitalPinToPCICR(pin)) {        // Is it a PCint pin?
      nPCICR  = digitalPinToPCICRbit(pin); // 0, 1, 2 for p's PCICR bit#
      maskBitPC = digitalPinToPCMSKbit(pin);
      PCInum =  nPCICR*8+ getBitfromBV(maskBitIO);
    }
  }
  if (!cc)         // At end of string? If so,
    --c;           // allow for caller incrementing c
  return 1;
}

void genCode (char *affix, char *pinsList) {
  char *portLet = "?ABCDEFGHIJKL?";
  enum { portMax=12 };
  byte readmask;        // Input-bits mask
  byte port;            // Port #

  snprintf(buffi, sizeof(buffi), "\n// %s : pins %s", affix, pinsList);
  Serial.println(buffi);

  //==================================================================
  // Generate  "byte get<affix>() { // Get pins <list>"
  //              return PINu & mu | PINv & mv | ...
  //            }"
  nbuff = snprintf(buffi, sizeof(buffi), "byte get%s () { // Get pins", affix);
  for (port=1; port<=portMax; ++port) {
    for (readmask=0, c = pinsList; getPinNumber(); ++c) {
      if (pinPort==port) {
    nbuff += snprintf(buffi+nbuff, sizeof(buffi)-nbuff, "% d,", pin);
    readmask |= maskBitIO;
      }
    }
    if (readmask) buffi[nbuff-1] = ';'; // Replace extra , by ;
  }
  Serial.println(buffi);    // Print first line of get...() function
  nbuff = snprintf(buffi, sizeof(buffi), "  return");
  for (port=1; port<=portMax; ++port) {
    for (readmask=0, c = pinsList; getPinNumber(); ++c) {
      if (pinPort==port) {
    readmask |= maskBitIO;
      }
    }
    if (readmask) 
      nbuff += snprintf(buffi+nbuff, sizeof(buffi)-nbuff, " PIN%c & 0x%02x |",
            portLet[port], readmask);
  }
  snprintf(buffi+nbuff-2, sizeof(buffi)-nbuff, ";\n}"); // -2 loses extra " |"
  Serial.println(buffi);  // Print last two lines of get...() function

  //==================================================================
  // Generate  "void put<affix>(byte w) { // Put pins <list>"
  //              PORTu = PINu & ~mu | w & mu;
  //              ...
  //            }"
  nbuff = snprintf(buffi, sizeof(buffi), "void put%s () { // Put pins", affix);
  for (port=1; port<=portMax; ++port) {
    for (readmask=0, c = pinsList; getPinNumber(); ++c) {
      if (pinPort==port) {
    nbuff += snprintf(buffi+nbuff, sizeof(buffi)-nbuff, "% d,", pin);
    readmask |= maskBitIO;
      }
    }
    if (readmask) buffi[nbuff-1] = ';'; // Replace extra , by ;
  }
  Serial.println(buffi);    // Print first line of put...() function
  for (port=1; port<=portMax; ++port) {
    for (readmask=0, c = pinsList; getPinNumber(); ++c) {
      if (pinPort==port) {
    readmask |= maskBitIO;
      }
    }
    if (readmask) {
      snprintf(buffi, sizeof(buffi), "  PORT%c = PIN%c & 0x%02x | w & 0x%02x;",
           portLet[port], portLet[port], (byte)(~readmask), readmask);
      Serial.println(buffi);  // Print a port-setting line of put...() function
    }
  }
  Serial.println("}");  // Print last line of put...() function

  //=================================================================
  // Generate ISR's:  Process 3 possible pin-change interrupt vectors
  vecmask = 0;
  for (byte ivect=0; ivect < 3; ++ivect) {
    byte sinPort=15;        // currently-in-use same port #
    intmask[ivect] = 0;
    byte busyvect=0;              // Assume vector not used
    byte readmask=0;              // Input mask
    // Loop to see if vector is used
    for (c = pinsList; getPinNumber(); ++c) {
      if (nPCICR == ivect) {
    ++busyvect; sinPort = pinPort;  // Bits on same port get read once
    vecmask |= 1<<ivect;
    intmask[ivect] |= 1<<maskBitPC;
      }
    }
    if (busyvect) {     // If vector is busy, create its ISR
      snprintf(buffi, sizeof(buffi), "ISR(PCINT%d_vect) {", ivect);
      Serial.println(buffi);
      nbuff = 0;
      for (c = pinsList; getPinNumber(); ++c) {
        // See if it's a PCint pin, and on the current vector
    if (digitalPinToPCICR(pin) && nPCICR == ivect) {
      intmask[ivect] |= 1<<maskBitPC;
      readmask |= digitalPinToBitMask(pin);
      nbuff += snprintf(buffn+nbuff, sizeof(buffn)-nbuff, " %d,", pin);
      if (pinPort != sinPort) {
        snprintf(buffi, sizeof(buffi), "Pin %d's port #%d isn't #%d", 
             pin, pinPort, sinPort);
        Serial.println(buffi);
      }
    }
      }
      snprintf(buffi, sizeof(buffi), "  byte datum = PIN%c & 0x%02x; // Read pins %s\n}",
           portLet[sinPort], readmask, buffn);
      Serial.println(buffi);
    }
  }
  snprintf(buffi, sizeof(buffi), "void setup%s(byte ioMode, byte enablePCI) {", affix);
  Serial.println(buffi);
  for (c = pinsList; getPinNumber(); ++c) {
    nbuff = snprintf(buffi, sizeof(buffi), "  pinMode(%2d, ioMode); // %2d, P%c%d",
         pin, pin, portLet[pinPort], getBitfromBV(maskBitIO));

    if (maskBitPC)
      snprintf(buffi+nbuff, sizeof(buffi)-nbuff, "   PCINT %d", PCInum);
    Serial.println(buffi);
  }
  Serial.println("  if (enablePCI) {");
  for (byte ivect=0; ivect < 3; ++ivect) {
    if (intmask[ivect]) {
      snprintf(buffi, sizeof(buffi), "    PCMSK%d |= 0x%02x;", ivect, intmask[ivect]);
      Serial.println(buffi);
    }
  }

  snprintf(buffi, sizeof(buffi), "    PCIFR  |= 0x%02x; // clear PC interrupts if any",
       vecmask);
  Serial.println(buffi);
  snprintf(buffi, sizeof(buffi), "    PCICR  |= 0x%02x; // enable PC interrupts\n  }\n}",
       vecmask);
  Serial.println(buffi);
}

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  while (!Serial) ;             // wait for serial stream to connect
  Serial.println("Starting Code Generation");
  genCode ("A0A1",  "14,15\0"); // A0, A1 on a nano
  genCode ("Pair78",  "7,8");
  genCode ("Trip346",  "3,4,6");
  genCode ("Quad789A", "7,8,9,10");
  genCode ("Hex8toD",  "8,9,10,12,11,13");
  genCode ("LotsSmall", "2,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,19,20,21,22,28,29,30,31,37");
  genCode ("LotsBig",   "31,37,38,37,38,45,46,52,53,54,55,61,62,63,69,70,71,76");
  Serial.println("Ending Code Generation");
  Serial.end();
}

void loop() {
}
```